# Bash command to remove several nested directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

I made a mistake and created nested directories such as:

```
dir1/dir2_A/out/dir2_A
    file1
    file2 
    out

dir1/dir2_B/out/dir2_B
    file1
    file2 
    out

dir1/dir2_C/out/dir2_C
    file1
    file2 
    out

...
```

How can I remove the all intermediate directories:

```
dir1/dir2_A/out/dir2_A/ → dir1/dir2_A/
dir1/dir2_B/out/dir2_B/ → dir1/dir2_B/
dir1/dir2_C/out/dir2_C/ → dir1/dir2_C/
```

etc., to get this in `dir1`?

```
dir1/dir2_A
    file1
    file2 
    out

dir1/dir2_B
    file1
    file2 
    out

dir1/dir2_C
    file1
    file2 
    out
```

Comment: Is `rm -rf dir1/dir2_*/out` what you want?

Comment: This move will remove the file inside the directory

Comment: Do you mean "move the files so that they are not in the `out` sub-directory but in the directory that contains the `out` sub-directory"?  Using 'remove' sends the wrong message.

Comment: well you are right I could move the directories into the ```dir1```

Comment: If you have the Perl-based `rename` (occasionally `prename`) script/program, you can use `rename 's%/out/%/%' dir1/*/out/*` command to move the files.  Failing that, you're into looping over the files: `for file in dir1/*/out/*; do newdir=$(dirname $(dirname "$file")); mv "$file" "$newdir"; done`. You could come up with some variations on that theme that would run `mv` less often.

Answer (score 0):

Descent to the files, move everything the levels up.
Next remove the empty dirs.
Use parentheses for a subshell so you will return from d1 without `cd ../..`.

```
for d1 in dir1/*/*/*; do
    test -d "$d1" || continue
    (cd "$d1" && mv * ../.. )
done
# Cleanup without `rm -r` avoiding errors when something went wrong
rmdir dir1/*/out/* 
rmdir dir1/*/out
```